# Jquery Mobile Page load from External Rel or Complete Refresh in Multipage file

Tags: jquery-mobile, pageload

I am trying to find where to place an event which must only trigger on the first page load of my multi-page jquery mobile page, or on a complete browser refresh. I do not wish the event to be triggered by my movement between the pages within the multi-page document.

I have found the below technique to work.

```
        $('[data-role=page]').live('pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
            var $et = $(event.target);
            if($et.attr('id')=='query'){
                //Do event
            }
        });
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks for the help!

Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to tweak it a bit:

Set a flag in pageinit and reset on first load. Not the cleanest way, but may have to do it in your case..

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
   firstpageloaded = false;
});

$('[data-role=page]').on('pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
  if ( false == firstpageloaded ){
     firstpageloaded = true;
     //Do Event
  }
});
```

Also, `live` is being deprecated and `on` should be used..